# Use of colon when addressing someone

Tags: colons

When addressing someone in an email (I understand grammar rules are pretty loose in this medium), should the sentence after the colon start with a capitalized letter? For example:

> *Example A:*
>
> I'm going to bring my car. David: What about you?
>
> *Example B:*
>
> I'm going to bring my car. David: what about you?

If a colon is the incorrect punctuation used in this scenario, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 5 examples of colon usage in your question. All three that have the word "example" before them are Ok.

Here is a short [list](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp) of rules on how and when to use colons.

But the punctuation after the name "David" should be a comma instead. This is because you are using "direct address." This is also true in [business writing](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/02/using_commas_wi.html) and an email.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a colon here. It suggests that David is the speaker of "what about you?" A comma seems to me to be the correct punctuation. If you put "David" at the end of the sentence, it would have to be "What about you, David?"

Comment: The example of putting "David" at the end of the sentence makes sense!

Comment: +1 to this comment for explaining the potential confusion resulting from the colon.